Center of mass of a solid sphere with spherical cavity

As shown in figure, when a spherical cavity (centred at O) of radius 1 is cut out of a uniform sphere of radius R (centred at C), the centre of mass of remaining (shaded) part of sphere is at G, i.e, on the surface of the cavity. R can be detemined by the equation :
(1) (R2 – R + 1) (2 – R) = 1
(2) (R2 + R – 1) (2 – R) = 1
(3) (R2 + R + 1) (2 – R) = 1
(4) (R2 – R – 1) (2 – R) = 1
By concept of COM m1R1 = m2R2

Remaining mass x (2 - R) = cavity mass x (R - I)
(R3 – 1) (2 – R) = R – 1 (R2 + R + 1) (2 – R) = 1
In this question why are we taking the axis c for measuring the coordinates. shouldn't it be measured from G as the center of mass lies over there
why are we using the mass of the leftover sphere shouldn't it be
The mass of complete sphere×distance from center of mass =mass of spherical cavity (-ve)×distance from center of mass
When we use
m1x1+m2x2÷(m1+m2)=xcom the answer matches
So what mistake and I making
Again I am not asking for answer, I am asking what is the problem with my approach as it is the way how center of mass is defined
